# My SQLにPHPで接続

Tags: php, sql

My SQLにPHPで接続することは可能ですか？

また Oracle とはなにがちがいますか？

Comment: ひとつの質問でふたつのことを聞こうとしないでください。ふたつの質問に分けることを検討するか、ふたつのことがどう繋がっているのかを [edit] して説明していただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: 質問をする前に検索は試みましたか？スタックオーバーフローだけでも、いくつも上がっています。[検索結果](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bphp%5d%20%5bmysql%5d%e3%80%80%e6%8e%a5%e7%b6%9a)。「[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)」にもありますが、まずは検索してみて質問を整理してみましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My SQLにPHPで接続することは可能ですか？

この質問の答えは Yes か No かしかありえなくて、んで Yes (それ以上は蛇足)
オイラのこの答えが気に入らないのなら、それは質問が悪い（と断定します）。

> また Oracle とはなにがちがいますか？

何と Oracle が違うのかわからないので答えにくいです ( PHP と Oracle の違いを訊ねているとも読み取れます) まあ普通に MySQL と Oracle の違いなら本家サイトに行くのが確実でしょう。
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23573_01/doc.21/b63054/oracle_mysql_compared.htm

あとライセンス料や保守費用が違いすぎます。検索すればすぐ見つかると思うので略・まあ Oracle も MySQL も (SQLServer も) 個人で使うにはコスト高すぎです（ありえないのレベル）